# Hi -- How to calculate present week and previous year same week on a date parameter in tableau.This date parameter needs to ISO week format

Tags: tableau-api

I have a date which should be ISO week, How can I calculate present week for this year and same week last year in tableau.
Right now the week is 15 t week for this year According to ISO week,need to calculate current week sales for ths year as well same 15 th week sales last year.We canot have month logic as ISO doesn't have Month concept.
It should be max of ISO week this year compared to same for last year.

Thanks,

Comment: Try dragging the date field onto rows (make sure Year is the result) and then drag the same field onto columns but select "Week Number" and then drag "sales" onto the marks pane you will see a plot showing the comparable weeks in different years. You can then filter to cover the specific period comparisons you want.

Comment: But one column needs to be current YTD,priorYTD,Current week and Prior Week.

Comment: But those are achievable from my solution by using table calculations.